Keycloak giving login error with correct username and password
I am facing some weird issue in KEYCLOAK, it is not coming always but sometime when we use system extensively it used to came.
Could anyone please give some idea why this error is coming...
When it comes we are unable to login and on UI we see username or password invalid.
We are using docker container for running keycloak service.
We are not using master realm, we have created our own realm and users and deleted the master realm.
This Issue is not frequent and it came when we use our system regularly.
Also there is no work around lastly we have to delete and create keycloak docker container again to solve this.
KEYCLOAK Version - 19.0.1
Thanks in Advance.
2024-12-19 06:38:28,750 WARN [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-12) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=c0d4199a-2897-4797-a484-xxxxxxxxx, clientId=test-abc, userId=null, ipAddress=10.xxx.xx.xxx, error=user_not_found, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, redirect_uri=https://10.xxx.xx.xxx/ream_name/, code_id=1bd12e92-8533-40ae-89ef-1111111xxxxx, username=admin, authSessionParentId=1bd12e92-8533-40ae-89ef-8888xxxxx, authSessionTabId=95tF4o5XXXX
I tried checking logs and found the realm, clientId is correct.
Username is present but the UserId is coming as null.
If I restart the containers it will solve the issue but users will be delete in that case.

Try to use the lastest version of keycloak. Also do not delete Master realm, just add your realm and use it.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
